# Can't set up remote vscode-server via ssh

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, ssh, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

I'm trying to set up a remote vscode-server on my raspberry pi and access it via ssh. When connecting to it via ssh in my desktop vscode-instance, the setup fails, and I don't really know what the problem is here.

These are the error messages the setup shows before aborting:

```
[23:58:37.984] stderr> mv: cannot move 'vscode-server-linux-arm64/bin' to './bin': Directory not empty
[23:58:37.984] stderr> mv: cannot move 'vscode-server-linux-arm64/extensions' to './extensions': Directory not empty
[23:58:38.364] stderr> mv: cannot move 'vscode-server-linux-arm64/node_modules' to './node_modules': Directory not empty
[23:58:38.364] stderr> mv: cannot move 'vscode-server-linux-arm64/out' to './out': Directory not empty
[23:58:38.365] > ERROR: /home/pi/.vscode-server-oss/bin/c3511e6c69bb39013c4a4b7b9566ec1ca73fc4d5/node or /home/pi/.vscode-server-oss/bin/c3511e6c69bb39013c4a4b7b9566ec1ca73fc4d5/bin/code-server-oss don't exist
[23:58:38.366] > Already attempted local download, failing
```

I tried removing the existing directories and restarting the setup, but that did nothing.

Comment: What command did u run?

Comment: @Elidor I started the setup from within vscode by just connecting to the pi-host via ssh, and it automatically starts the installation. Basically like [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh#_connect-to-a-remote-host)

Comment: I would try to manually delete these folders on Raspberry Pi and try to connect again

Comment: I already did that, but forgot to mention it. I edited the question.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/4307#issuecomment-762019918

Comment: Just tried it. Didn't work either, sadly.

Comment: OSS version is unable to use the "remote" feature. It's a known thing. To use "remote" you must download the MS branded/built version from their website. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/faq#_why-arent-the-remote-development-extensions-or-their-components-open-source

Comment: I didn't know that, but thank you very much. Works now.